# Reactjs duplicates inserted object on previously inserted objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, reactjs, duplicates

I have come across a pretty strange case and like to see what could be causing it. I am making a recipe box which can contain recipes in ReactJS. It starts with these initial recipes:

```
    var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      recipes: [{
        id: 0,
        name: "Carbonana",
        ingredients: ["Spaghetti", "Banana-sauce", "Bacon", "Cream", "Oregano"]
      }, {
        id: 1,
        name: "Roasted duck with sweet potatoes",
        ingredients: ["Duck", "Sweet chili sauce", "Small potatoes", "Sugar", "Butter"]
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Baked potatoes",
        ingredients: ["Baking potatoes", "Bacon", "Creme Fraiche", "Garlic", "Onions"]
      }]
    }
  }
```

Then you can add your own recipe with a name and ingredients via. a form.
In AddRecipe component:

```
 <Form >
  <ControlLabel>Recipe Name</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        placeholder="Beef Cheese"
        onChange={this.handleRecipeNameChange}
      />
  <hr/>
    <FormGroup controlId="formControlsTextarea">
  <ControlLabel>Ingredients</ControlLabel>
  <FormControl onChange={this.handleIngredientsChange}
 componentClass="textarea" placeholder="salt,pepper,cheese,beef" />
</FormGroup>
  <ButtonToolbar>
<Button onClick={this.handleAddRecipe} bsStyle="primary">Add Recipe</Button>
  <Button onClick={this.closeModal}>Cancel</Button>
```

The ingredients can be typed in the form seperated by comma's. Here is the handle methods for the form:

In AddRecipe component:

```
  handleAddRecipe: function() {
    this.closeModal();
    this.props.addRecipe(this.state.recipe);
  },

  handleRecipeNameChange: function(e) {
    var recipe = this.state.recipe;
    recipe.name = e.target.value;
    this.setState({recipe: recipe});
  },

  handleIngredientsChange: function(e) {
    var recipe = this.state.recipe;
    recipe.ingredients = e.target.value.split(",");
    this.setState({recipe: recipe});
  }
```

Finally there is addRecipe(recipe) which receives a recipe from AddRecipe component and adds it to the recipes array of recipe objects. Each of the recipes should have a unique id:

```
  addRecipe: function(recipe) {
    var currentRecipes = this.state.recipes;
    console.log("currentRecipes ");
    console.log(currentRecipes);
    recipe.id = currentRecipes.length;
    currentRecipes.push(recipe);
    console.log("recipe added: ");
    console.log(recipe);
    console.log(recipe.id + " last id!");
    this.setState({recipes: currentRecipes});
  }
```

If I add 1 recipe, it gets the unique id of 3, this is the output, this is fine and as I expect:

```
    recipes: [{
        id: 0,
        name: "Carbonana",
        ingredients: ["Spaghetti", "Banana-sauce", "Bacon", "Cream", "Oregano"]
      }, {
        id: 1,
        name: "Roasted duck with sweet potatoes",
        ingredients: ["Duck", "Sweet chili sauce", "Small potatoes", "Sugar", "Butter"]
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Baked potatoes",
        ingredients: ["Baking potatoes", "Bacon", "Creme Fraiche", "Garlic", "Onions"]
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "Something new and exciting!",
        ingredients: ["More beef", "Onions"]
      }]
```

Now I open up the form from AddRecipe component again, and type in a new recipe. But this time it simply inserts the same object again:

```
recipes: [{
            id: 0,
            name: "Carbonana",
            ingredients: ["Spaghetti", "Banana-sauce", "Bacon", "Cream", "Oregano"]
          }, {
            id: 1,
            name: "Roasted duck with sweet potatoes",
            ingredients: ["Duck", "Sweet chili sauce", "Small potatoes", "Sugar", "Butter"]
          }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "Baked potatoes",
            ingredients: ["Baking potatoes", "Bacon", "Creme Fraiche", "Garlic", "Onions"]
          }, {
            id: 4,
            name: "Something even more new and improved!!",
            ingredients: ["Day old potatoes", "salt"]
          }, {
            id: 4,
            name: "Something even more new and improved!!",
            ingredients: ["Day old potatoes", "salt"]
          }]
```

What I notice is that it duplicates the latest entered object across all previous entered objects. Why is this? You can see the page in action on http://codepen.io/Hylleh/pen/pbqNbO?editors=1010

Comment: There are several points in your code where you mutate the state object itself by doing something like `var currentRecipes = this.state.recipes;` and then modifying `currentRecipes`. Change every such statement with `var currentRecipes = Object.assign([], this.state.recipes);` and then retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that's preventing you from adding new recipes is the fact that your `AddRecipe` component is using `this.props.addRecipe` and passing a *reference* to its state.

Your `App` component takes this reference, and adds it to an array over and over again.  Thus, every item in this array past index 2 will always be the exact same reference to the same `AddRecipe` state, meaning they will share the same `id`, `name`, and `ingredients` properties.  Since you are using the `id` as the keys for each of these recipes, React will not render any recipe after the first one you add, because every additional recipe will share the same key as the last one.

If you open your console on that page, you'll see this error after trying to add two recipes:

> Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `4`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.

The solution to this problem is to avoid saving references of your `AddRecipe` component's state to your `App` component's state.  I would modify the `App.addRecipe` function like so:

```
addRecipe(recipe) {
    // Clone passed state reference and set id to the correct value
    const newRecipe = Object.assign({}, recipe, {
        id: this.state.recipes.length
    });

    // Replace recipes with a new array that has newRecipe appended at the end
    this.setState({
        recipes: [...this.state.recipes, newRecipe]
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now. I didn't know I was passing around a reference.

Comment: Happy to help :) Make sure you accept the answer if it solved your problem!